# Dockerizing Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker, dockerfile

I have a working app using Spring Framework + AngularJs front-end.
I do deploy it on amazon AWS before by simply packaging `mvn package` into .war file.

Now I need to setup a linux env in docker locally to debug some additional functionality (Using windows as the main OS) and preferably to deploy this docker container in future.

I do seen some articles on dockerizing the Spring Boot app.

This is the example dockerfile from `spring.io`

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

My question is - **how do I run my .war file on docker** container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to run this application on your local Linux machine, then you can create this Dockerfile in the same directory where the WAR file exists.

```
    FROM tomcat:8.0.21-jre8
    RUN [“rm”, “-rf”, “/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT”] 
    COPY dbconnect.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
    CMD [“catalina.sh”, “run”]
```

You can then build the Docker image and provide your custom tag:

```
     docker build -t <your-username>/tomcat-example:latest .
```

Finally you can run this container.

```
     docker run -p 8080:8080 -d --name tomcat  <your-username>/tomcat-example:latest
```

You can check out these detailed examples here if need to run this application with a database or a web server.

https://github.com/dchqinc/dchq-docker-java-example

https://dzone.com/refcardz/java-containerization

Answer (score 1):

You don't deploy a `.war` file in docker just like you deploy it into a tomcat server. You need to have a `main(String args[])` entry point which is also specified in your jar's manifest file. Your `app.jar` specified as `ENTRYPOINT` will then run your `main()`. Inside the `main()` you can run an embedded web server which runs your application.

Comment: can you please show the example how is the `main(String args[])` will looks like.

Comment: actually how it all must looks like. i hope this question can be useful for others

Answer (score 0):

If you configure/package your Spring Boot app as an executable .jar instead of a .war (Spring Boot Initializr will do this for you if you select the .jar option), then running it in your container is a matter of adding an entrypoint to run java with -jar and your jar name, like

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/yourapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]